# C# Check line for data type

Tags: c#, cmd

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Operation;
        Operation = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

How to handle if non-Integer values are passed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
int Operation;
bool succeeded = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Operation);
```

the `TryParse` method attempts to parse the value.  If it succeeds the value will be placed into `Operation`.  The return value of the method indicates if it succeeded or not.